# Is it possible to use React-navigation to navigate to a native Swift/Obj-C/Java/Kotlin screen like wix/react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to use react-navigation to navigate to native code/screens? I've done this with wix/react-native-navigation in the past and its not bad, but I'm trying to avoid having multiple navigation libs in my code since I already use react-navigation. I can't seem to find any docs or past examples of how to do this if it's even possible.

I'm also open to other alternatives if they exist and are considered industry leaders/ have good docs.

If anyone has some background with this and is happy to share some examples that would be greatly appreciated!